# How to backup Mysql database on Windows 2008 R2 to Amazon S3?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I've a MySql db running on a Windows 2008 R2 machine. I want to back up my DB every night to Amazon S3.

I'm new to this field, so can anyone guide me through the steps.

Any blog link is also appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: you mean to say I should use mysqldump and windows scheduler? Cron is for Linux. My DB is on Windows 2008 server.

Comment: That's what he means - unless you want to mirror your S3 instance with your local instance, which I doubt you want to do. Unfortunately your running Windows - should you be running Linux there are several scripts out there you could use...

Comment: OK, won't be that tough to make a Windows specific one. Let me work on it & if it works I shall share it here for anyone else looking for the same. I ain't an admin person, but let me give it a shot.

Comment: If you are looking for a tool to backup MySQL Server on Windows to Amazon S3 automatically, then you can use MySQLBackupFTP http://mysqlbackupftp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to script it yourself and test it, I would suggest using a commercial package (safer option since they have many customers and tested it under different conditions).  One option would be to use software from Zmanda. They have a good solution for MySQL and support Amazon S3 so it should be fairly easy.